# Python: switching from optparse to argparse

Tags: python, shell, command-line-arguments, argparse, optparse

After switching from optparse to argparse - I'm experiencing strange errors. Argparse parse args only if leave no space:

```
myScript.py -oOpt
```

or put an equal sign:

```
myScript.py -o=Opt
```

and it doesn't work the normal way:

```
myScript.py -o Opt
```

Here's my argparse initialization:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# to get description use the -h flag

import argparse, os, sys


# ======================
# Python2.7 is expected:

if sys.version_info[0] != 2 or sys.version_info[1] < 7:
    sys.exit('This program needs Python2.7+')


# ==========
# preambule:

desc = """Enter dirs in the current dir and makes gro out of state.cpt there."""
# parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc, version='2.3', formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('-w', '--workWith',
                    help = 'to specify a Gromacs exec suffix', 
                    dest = 'wW',
                    action = 'store',
                    default = '-4.5.5-single',
                    )
parser.add_argument('-g', '--gro',
                    help = '.gro postfix: <nameOfTheDir><postfix>.gro', 
                    dest = 'myGroPostfix',
                    action = 'store',
                    default = "_membrane",
                    )
parser.add_argument('-H', '--here',
                    help = 'toggles - single (current) dir behaviour (the output will be state.gro)', 
                    dest = 'Here',
                    action = 'store_true',
                    )
parser.add_argument('-D', '--dirs',
                    help = 'include these dirs (python\'s rgxp in SINGLE quotes), defaults to \'\'', 
                    dest = 'inclDirs',
                    action = 'store',
                    default = '',
                    )

args = parser.parse_args()


print args.wW
```

**Edit**:

Even more:

```
 gmx_bk-simulate-mems.py -j bk-runs-mpi.bash -p 1 -w="-4.5.5-double_non-parallel_gcc" 2&> ../`date +%Y-%b-%d-%H%M%S`.log &
```

gives:

```
 gmx_bk-simulate-mems.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 2
```

it looks like `argparse` treats `2&>` as option (or `2&>` and `../date +%Y-%b-%d-%H%M%S.log` as options)!

**Edit 2**:

So to summarize:

- For `argparse` - `"-4.5.5-double_non-parallel_gcc"` is a bad option name - and that's why it is required to write is as `-w="-4.5.5-double_non-parallel_gcc"`. For `optparse` and `bash` (!) this is fine. `bash` even gives an error at `-w="-4.5.5-double_non-parallel_gcc"` - it thinks that the arg is `="-4.5.5-double_non-parallel_gcc"` (!);
- There's no such thing as `2&>`. `2>` should might be used and it gives no errors;
- This is `shell` who splits the line into args, not `python`;
- `argparse` is much better than `optparse`.

Comment: Putting your code in `tmp.py`, both `python tmp.py -w3` and `python tmp.py -w 3` print '3' for me.

Comment: @chepner: yes it does... Actually the problem gives line 75 in [gmx_bk-get-results.bash](https://github.com/bk322/bk-bio/blob/master/gmx_bk-get-results.bash): if one removes `=` from that line - the script gives error - as if I don't give it `"$wW"`. In order to reproduce one needs also to get [bk-copies-from-dirs.py](https://github.com/bk322/bk-goodies/blob/master/bk-copies-from-dirs.py) and [gmx_bk-cpt2gmx.py](https://github.com/bk322/bk-bio/blob/master/gmx_bk-cpt2gmx.py)... Everything was working fine on `optparse`. I hope somebody will see the problem "theoretically".

Comment: Pedantic comment: You don't need the version checker. If you use Python 3, the print statement at the bottom will cause a syntax error and the script won't even be loaded. If you use Python 2.6 or below, the script will fail upon importing `argparse`, before you even get to the version check.

Comment: This was a very interesting question, though, and thinking about it taught me some new things about `argparse`. Thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, it is necessary to make a small distinction. The `argparse` module does not parse your command-line arguments, the shell does. The shell is responsible for transforming the line you type in the shell into tokens, which are then passed to `sys.argv`, a python array/sequence of command-line arguments. The `argparse` module simply makes sense of what appears in `sys.argv`.

This distinction will clarify both of the "errors" you noticed. First, consider `-w "-4.5.5-double_non-parallel_gcc"` (note the lack of equal sign). The shell parses these two tokens as `-w` and `-4.5.5-double_non-parallel_gcc`, and both of these strings are passed to sys.argv. Without the equal sign, this appears to be two options: `-w` (with no argument) and `-4` with `.5.5-double_non-parallel_gcc` as an argument. You need the equals sign so that everything is parsed as a single token.

**EDITED SECTION**

As for `2&>`, it is impossible for argparse to control whether a given token is treated as an argument or not. If something appears in sys.argv, that means your *shell* is treating it as an argument.

The telltale sign here is the error message. Note that the message is not `unrecognized arguments: 2&>`, but rather, `unrecognized arguments: 2`. Your shell recognizes "&>" as output redirection, and parses the rest of the line (including the log file) accordingly. The only argument being passed is the "2", because `2&>` is not a real type of redirection. (`&>` already covers both stderr and stdout, so what would the `2` add to it?)

In a comment, you claimed that `optparse` could "handle" the "2&>". That is not actually the case. The `optparse` module did exactly what `argparse` does, but `optparse` does not validate positional arguments like `argparse` does. In fact, `optparse` is letting a real programming error (in this case, using `2&>` as a type of shell redirection) slip by undetected! You should post your original optparse code, but I suspect you parsed your arguments as follows:

```
opt, args = parser.parse_args()
```

Your script takes no positional arguments, so I imagine you did nothing else with `args` afterwards. But if you were to inspect `args`, you would find that `2` was considered a positional argument!

In general, if a script takes no positional arguments and you use `optparse`, it is good practice to verify that you receive no positional arguments, like so:

```
opt, args = parser.parse_args()
if args:
    parser.error("script takes no positional arguments")
```

The `argparse` module does that work for you, which is what puts it miles ahead of `optparse` (among other reasons).

Comment: Everything was working fine with `optparse`. But it looks like that `"-4.5.5-double_non-parallel_gcc"` is a "bad option name", and while `optparse` leaves the quotes, `argparse` does not - hence the error. But what about the `2&>` part? It was working fine with `optparse`. It works fine with no 2: `&>`. I can live this way - but isn't it strange? It should be solved. It should work with `2&>` as well.

Comment: I've edited my answer above to address your concern. Again, `2&>` is not a real redirection flag; `2>` is, and `&>` is, and even `2>&1`, but not `2&>`. If you don't believe me, try it with a shell built-in: `ls 2&> tmp.txt`. The `&>` captures stderr, so you won't see it immediately, but if you look at tmp.txt you'll see the error message.